# css not found (404) - it's adding another css to my path

Tags: html, css

I have a normal HTML page on my IIS8 development machine. Very basic and doesn't contain any code yet.

To the HEAD I've added a css file deceleration I've created:

```
<link href="css/catalog.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

When inspecting with either chrome or fiddler it reports a 404 - but not because the file isn't there - but because it's adding another css folder:

```
GET http://localhost/mywebsite/message/css/css/catalog.css 404 (Not Found)
```

which should actually be:

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/message/css/catalog.css
```

strange thing is that if I change the name of the folder to anything but CSS it works.

any ideas to why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: What's the path to the HTML file that you have your `link` in?

Comment: try removing `css/` from the href

Comment: @Chris the HTML is in a sub-directory of my site. The css is a folder in that sub-directory.

Comment: @KillerR tried it - then it doesn't add any folder.

Comment: I understand, but what is that subdirectory? This will help us understand what's going on given the CSS file's full path.

Comment: used to this <link href="../css/catalog.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Answer (score 0):

Just use this and you'll be good to go:

```
<link href="catalog.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**EDIT:**

```
<link href="/catalog.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Read the comments on the question. Someone already suggested this and @developer82 already tried it and reported the results.